# How to customize title / tooltip for fullcalendar events?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, fullcalendar

so i found some solution for displaying title on hovering full calendar events but it looks ugly. Is there any way i can customize it?

this is my code for that part:

```
function initialize() {//.. 
        var $element = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
                element.find('span.fc-title').attr('data-toggle', 'tooltip');
                element.find('span.fc-title').attr('title', event.title);
            }}
```

But it just displays basic title, i will insert image of it. Thanks in advance for any advice, If you need more code i can provide.

[image]

Comment: Can you create fiddle for with libraries you are using to help you better?

Comment: The eventRender documentation actually has an example of one way to do this:l and get a nicer visual effect: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventRender

Comment: "But it just displays basic title"...so, what else did you want it to do? It isn't clear precisely what the problem really is.

Answer (score 1):

```
eventMouseover: function(event, jsEvent) {
            var tooltip = '<div class="calendarTooltip" style="padding-left:10px; text-align: center;width:185px;height:35px;background:#126da2; border-radius: 8px; color: white;position:absolute;z-index:10001;">' + event.title + '</div>';
            var $tool = $(tooltip).appendTo('body');
            $(this).mouseover(function(e) {
                $(this).css('z-index', 10000);
                        $tool.fadeIn('1000');
                        $tool.fadeTo('10', 1.9);
            }).mousemove(function(e) {
                $tool.css('top', e.pageY + 10);
                $tool.css('left', e.pageX + 20);
            });
            },
            eventMouseout: function(event, jsEvent) {
            $(this).css('z-index', 8);
            $('.calendarTooltip').remove();
            },
```

This is the working solution i made, it works fine. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this -
element.find('span.fc-title').append(`"<img src = 'img link' />"`);

or try -
element.find('span.fc-title').innerHTML += `"<img src = 'img link' />"`;

Comment: I managed to create my own solution, thanks for this. Check below